# How do I share an enum definition between contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, inheritance

I have two related contracts, let's call them `Supplier` and `Producer`.

A `Supplier` can have a `State` of `inactive`, `active`, or `kaput`, but only `active` suppliers can be added to a `Producer`.

So something like this:

```
contract Supplier {
  enum State { inactive, active, kaput }
  State constant DEFAULT_STATE = State.inactive

  State public status;

  function Supplier() {
    status = DEFAULT_STATE;
  }
}
```

But doing this doesn't work.

```
contract Producer {
  function addSupplier(Supplier _supplier) {
    require(_supplier.status == Supplier.State.active);
  }
}
```

I considered using an Interface but `enum` is specifically disallowed in an Interface.

How do I expose `enum` definitions to external contracts without resorting to something ugly like `require(uint(supplier.status) == 1);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enums defined inside a contract are by default accessible from other contracts. In Producer you can use the expressions:

- `Supplier.State.inactive`
- `Supplier.State.active`
- `Supplier.State.kaput`

Your code is not working because `public` state variables behave like functions from the perspective of other contracts. Try replacing this line:

`require(_supplier.status == Supplier.State.active);`

with this:

`require(_supplier.status() == Supplier.State.active);`